# Time complexity of the program?

Tags: algorithm, time, complexity-theory

```
1 i ← 1
2  while i < n/4
3   do
4    j ← 2i
5     while j < n
6       do
7         j ← j + 1
8     i ← i + 1


b) 1 i ← n
   2 while i > 1
   3   do
   4    j ← i
   5    while j < n
   6      do
   7        j ← 2j
   8    i ← i − 1


 c) 1 i ← 1
    2 while i < n
    3   do
    4     j ← 0
    5     while j ≤ i
    6       do
    7         j ← j + 1
    8     i ← 2i
```

Given these three programs, what would be the easiest approach in finding the time complexity for each one of these? I can tell that the first one is probably going to be O(n^2). But is there an easy approach to these to solve it consistently? I have an exam about it tomorrow.

Comment: Giving you the answers to your HW assignment is not going to benefit you at all, especially if you have an exam tomorrow. What you should do is neatly edit your question to include what you think the complexity of each question is and why.

Comment: I did not ask for solutions, nor are those HW assignments. I asked for help on how to solve such a problem since I dont know how to do it.

Answer (score 3):

(I'll ignore off-by-1, rounding etc. in the summation limits)

---

A)

In the inner loop you do `n - 2i - 1` operations. In the outer loop you do `n/4 - 1`. So the complexity is:

[image]

So your answer to the first one is correct.

---

B)

In the inner loop, `j` gets *doubled* every time, so grows exponentially; therefore the inner loop takes logarithmic time - `log (n / i)`. (base 2 but ignore WLOG). The division by `i` inside is because `j` starts from `i`, so is equivalent to starting from 1 and growing up to `n / i`. In the outer loop you do `n - 1` ops.

[image]

(Last step is from *Stirling's* approximation)

---

C)

In the inner loop you do `i + 1` ops. In the outer loop `i` grows exponentially from 1 to `n`, so `log n`.

[image]

---

N.B. I notice the significant discrepancy with TypeKazt's answers; this illustrates you can't simply "multiply" the inner loop's complexity with that of the outer loop, and that the boundary conditions for the inner loop are deterministically important.

---

EDIT: As added proof to my bold accusations against TypeKazt (hehe sorry buddy), here is some test data I got from a C# implementation:

[image]
[image]
[image]

As you can see, the complexity of A (linear scale) is `O(n^2)`, whereas those of B and C (log-log scales) are linear.

Code:

```
static int A(int n)
{
   int c = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < n / 4; i++)
      for (int j = 2 * i; j < n; j++)
         c++;
   return c;
}

static int B(int n)
{
   int c = 0;
   for (int i = n; i > 1; i--)
      for (int j = i; j < n; j *= 2)
         c++;
   return c;
}

static int C(int n)
{
   int c = 0;
   for (int i = 1; i < n; i *= 2)
      for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++)
         c++;
   return c;
}
```

---

P.S. I know SO's policy is not to babysit people, but I for one learn well by examples, so I hope this will help you to understand a simple analytical approach to complexity analysis.

Comment: thank you very much! in b) I do understand that the inner loop takes logarithmic time, but why is it divided by i, shouldnt it be substracted?

Comment: @justpolo I put it in the answer sorry

Comment: thank you so much again for your explanation! saved my life!