# Computing Tightest Big-Oh Bounds on Recurrence

Tags: algorithm, recursion, big-o, recurrence

In my Algorithms class we're learning about recurrences, but I'm completely lost and have no idea what to do. I found this pdf from Bowdoin  [Solving Recurrences with the Iteration/Recursion-tree](http://www.bowdoin.edu/~ltoma/teaching/cs231/fall07/Lectures/reccurences.pdf) and it explains it a bit better but the examples provided don't include Big Oh. I have one of the problems listed below. How do we manipulate the recurrence iteration tree to incorporate the O(n^2)? I would appreciate it if someone would be able to explain what to do in the case of Big Oh involving recurrences. Thank you

```
T(n) = T(n−4)+O(n^2)
```

Comment: Depending on how rigorous you need to be, you can just observe that `T(n) = O(n) * O(n^2)` = O(n^3)`. (You can only subtract 4 O(n) times before you reach your base case.)

Comment: Since there is only one recursive term, and whose coefficient is also one, it doesn't really give a *tree* of any kind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to follow up on the other answers by stating the following:

> You cannot simply, in the general case, naively multiply the number of occurrences by the complexity of each individual occurrence.

The safe thing to do would be to evaluate the recurrence *precisely* - i.e. without the O-notation, and "re-apply" the O-notation at the end by only taking the leading order term.

---

Let's look at the example. Define a function `S(n)` which computes the *precise* series value:

[image]

Let's assume that the recursion stops when `n <= 0`, then there are `floor(n / 4)` terms in the expansion series:

[image]

Where in step (*) we used the [standard formulae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula#Faulhaber_polynomials) for summing powers of natural numbers (positive integers), and in the last step we gathered all terms proportional to `n^3`, which is the leading power. Thus, we can **safely** conclude that **`T(n) = O(S(n)) = O(n^3)`**.

---

Where might a naive approach fail? Consider the following example:

[image]

Where `N` is a parameter equal to the *initial* value of `n`, i.e:

[image]

Now, what assumptions can we make in the event of a naive approach?

1. Since `n = N` initially, assume that the *lower* bound of the complexity is simply given by assuming `n = N` for *all* of the `log` terms. But this gives 0!
2. Assuming that the stopping condition is when `n = 1`, the largest term is also the last - `log N`. There are obviously `N` terms in the entire sum, so the final complexity is `O(N log N) = O(n log n)`.

(2) seems reasonable, but is it correct?

Let's use the above procedure:

[image]

Where we used some logarithm rules in (1) (2), and [*Stirling's approximation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) in (3). Therefore the final complexity `T(n)` is:

[image]

So as you can see, the naive multiplication approach gave us the wrong result of `O(n log n)` instead of `O(n)`.

Why did I bore you (apologies!) by choosing this rather abstruse counter-example? [Because I have seen this mistake made before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37712310/time-complexity-of-the-program).

Comment: @giusti but the `O(log N)` and `O(log n)` terms come from the *same* O-notation bracket, so have the same "weighting" (constant factor); therefore by setting `N = n` at the end they would cancel, and your approach would give `0` or `O(1)`. Only by using Stirling's approximation would you have obtained the *second order* term `O(n)`. I'm sure there are many more examples where further exploration is needed before a safe conclusion can be reached.

Comment: @giusti also one cannot simply assume that `O(log N/n)` can be *amortized* to `O(1)`, because the last few terms are of order `O(log N)`. We cannot directly assume that the contribution from these terms will be out-weighed by that of the others. I guess one could *intuitively* have inferred this, but without a somewhat more concrete proof I doubt examiners would be left satisfied.

Comment: Please be assured that I don't mean anyone offense by using the term "naive". It is simply to imply non-rigorous reasoning which may have hidden pitfalls.

Comment: I removed my comments because it was getting confusing and not contributing to anyone who reads this. If I can find a formal explanation I'll come back and share. I still insist that the "naive" approach will give you the right answer. It's just an issue with how you are treating `N` down the relation.

Comment: @giusti I don't think any further analysis would be "naive" anymore, since the "naive" one was simply multiplying some kind of amortized complexity with the number of occurrences. I don't see how that would directly lead to the second order term O(n) is all.

Comment: The fact that you use `N` bothers me a lot. The moment you choose a starting point, `N` becomes a constant, so all the big-O analysis that follows got me scratching my head. An equivalent relation would be `T(n) = T2(n,n)` and then `T2(n,n) = T(n-1,n) + O(log(n/n))`  *[actually, no, it wouldn't, but forget it]*. But I can't give you a stronger argument. No offense, but it feels like you "cheated". I can't think of a single actual relation where something like this would happen and the "navie" method would fail you.

Comment: @giusti It's not a constant, it is simply the starting value of `n`. Sure, the *first* O-term might look a little confusing as it cancels to zero, but the next term in the expansion would be `O(log(n/(n-1)))` and so on. I merely used `N` to emphasize that the `n` in the numerator *stays* as the initial `n`. Quite surprised that you would resort to calling it "cheating" in order to credit your own argument.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to offend. I'm just quite puzzled. You can say I am stubborn. That N looks very constant to me down your relation. At each step, the N in O(logN/n) depends on a value that was fixed before. But I'll withdraw, I don't have a good argument. Anyway, where did this relation come from? Some book?

Comment: @giusti It is an adapted version from another SO post (I linked it in the last sentence). There was a deleted answer which used the same "naive" method to arrive at `O(n log n)`. And yes, although in the definition of `S` it is constant, from the definition of `T` it is stated to be the "input" variable `n`, so in the end we cannot ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

You can just treat the big-O as any function, and then attempt to solve the recurrence. In this case, you could do

```
T(n)   = T(n-4)  + O(n²)
T(n-4) = T(n-8)  + O(n²)
T(n-8) = T(n-12) + O(n²)
.
.
.
T(0) = 0
```

Notice that `O(n²)` is essentially the same as `O((n - 4)²)`.

So by replacement you reach

```
T(n) = O(n²) + O(n²) + O(n²) + ... + 0
```

You can easily show that this summation has `n/4` terms. So this is

```
T(n) = ¼n * O(n²) = O(n³)
```

Alternatively, remember that *any* function in the form `f(n) = c*n²` is `O(n²)`. So you can also replace `O(n²)` with one of such functions and work asymptotically with the following inequality:

```
T(n) ≤ T(n-4) + c*n²
```

The rest follows pretty much the same idea.